# How to simulate distribution values from an ARIMA in order to plot as a fanchart

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I have the following time series of CPI data, which I am looking to create a fanchart (similar to the Bank of England Example in https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015-1/abel.pdf, or in `ggplot2` if that is possible).

So far, I have created an ARIMA model from my time series. I am looking for a solution on how to simulate a distribution of random variables from my model and plot it as a fanchart. I am looking to simulate 10 periods ahead for the distribution.

Here is a reproductible of my dataset `cpi`

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1356998400, 1359676800, 1362096000, 
1364774400, 1367366400, 1370044800, 1372636800, 1375315200, 1377993600, 
1380585600, 1383264000, 1385856000, 1388534400, 1391212800, 1393632000, 
1396310400, 1398902400, 1401580800, 1404172800, 1406851200, 1409529600, 
1412121600, 1414800000, 1417392000, 1420070400, 1422748800, 1425168000, 
1427846400, 1430438400, 1433116800, 1435708800, 1438387200, 1441065600, 
1443657600, 1446336000, 1448928000, 1451606400, 1454284800, 1456790400, 
1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 
1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1485907200, 1488326400, 
1491004800, 1493596800, 1496275200, 1498867200, 1501545600, 1504224000, 
1506816000, 1509494400, 1512086400, 1514764800, 1517443200, 1519862400, 
1522540800, 1525132800, 1527811200, 1530403200, 1533081600, 1535760000, 
1538352000, 1541030400, 1543622400, 1546300800, 1548979200, 1551398400, 
1554076800, 1556668800, 1559347200, 1561939200, 1564617600, 1567296000, 
1569888000, 1572566400, 1575158400, 1577836800, 1580515200, 1583020800, 
1585699200, 1588291200, 1590969600, 1593561600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), CPI = c(100.943613610327, 101.355726290109, 
101.920519704091, 102.251765014058, 102.399483334481, 102.654230611209, 
103.366370423635, 103.771996583604, 104.069828647932, 104.475897454947, 
104.745585890252, 104.9, 105.877675706645, 106.600613244374, 
107.25658797107, 108.285287342243, 108.607710827378, 108.935592526775, 
109.11670321665, 109.390661099815, 109.563232156331, 109.694215435852, 
109.939646273932, 109.754097918499, 110.601049654351, 110.415206179718, 
110.905507883552, 111.45837834832, 111.873469766967, 112.253828314821, 
112.699336213665, 113.056054221625, 113.204653466884, 113.387164759728, 
113.581282843726, 113.810860009533, 116.506784014018, 117.199721025597, 
118.107968739773, 118.823678758349, 119.420709143437, 119.808600479962, 
120.575551335206, 120.774779709305, 121.014544917053, 121.61732414169, 
121.917354377998, 122.116542025261, 126.058371342546, 126.285551233707, 
126.43426615261, 126.763103151148, 126.92061331762, 127.095652703716, 
127.146439944094, 127.257270861715, 127.754395868046, 127.897364611267, 
128.227889139291, 128.426778898969, 130.540032633942, 130.730222134177, 
130.87769195147, 131.302356289165, 131.797387843531, 132.126557217198, 
132.823218725753, 132.868685232286, 133.870800057958, 134.439906096246, 
135.351580975176, 135.040382301698, 136.620612224767, 136.503608878263, 
136.763944144826, 137.24925661824, 137.169191683167, 137.331600194512, 
137.656945057261, 137.792027588476, 137.792027588476, 138.493686354623, 
138.681976535356, 138.535078801086, 139.421769773802, 139.848223614133, 
139.983926150073, 139.504431667605, 139.994961370897, 140.280481556844, 
140.529583177439)), row.names = c(NA, -91L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the code for my model so far

```
# Load Packages
library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(tseries, tidyverse, urca, forecast, tbl2xts)


# Create a log transformation for CPI and convert from tibble to time series format

cpi.ts <- cpi %>% 
  mutate(CPI = log(CPI)) %>% 
  tbl_xts()

# Test for a unit root using an ADF test

adf.cpi.ts <- ur.df(cpi.ts, type = "none", selectlags = "AIC")
summary(adf.cpi.ts)

# Create an ARIMA Model using cpi.ts

arima <- auto.arima(cpi.ts)
```

and here are the results for `arima`

```
ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift 

Coefficients:
       drift
      0.0037
s.e.  0.0005

sigma^2 estimated as 2.255e-05:  log likelihood=354.77
AIC=-705.54   AICc=-705.4   BIC=-700.54
```

Could I go about doing this using the `arima.sim` function (and if yes, how could I go about doing it?). Ideally, I'm looking for my end solution to look something like the graph below (it would be even better if I could find a `ggplot2` solution though.

TIA[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions here -- how to simulate future values from the model, and how to plot the forecasts (or simulations) as a fan chart. Both can be done using the fable package.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)

# Create tsibble object
cpi <- cpi %>% 
  mutate(Date = yearmonth(Date)) %>%
  as_tsibble(index=Date)

# Fit ARIMA model to log data
fit <- cpi %>%
  model(arima = ARIMA(log(CPI)))

# Simulated future sample paths
fit %>%
  generate(times=20, h="1 year") %>%
  autoplot(.sim) + autolayer(cpi, CPI) +
  ylab("CPI") +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

```r
# Fan plot
fit %>%
  forecast(h="1 year") %>%
  autoplot(cpi, level=seq(10,90,by=10)) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you @Rob Hyndman, much appreciated! Perfect solution

Comment: Sorry @Rob Hyndman just one more question, Is there any way in which I can connect my actual line to the forecast fan (so without the gap that's in between them)? As well as any tips to change the colors of the fan? Apologies I'm not too familiar with the ```autoplot``` function

Comment: Look at the help file. `help(fabletools:::autoplot.fbl_ts)`. The `show_gap` argument can control the gap. `color` controls the color.

Comment: also noticed that the range the fan at the first forecast period is quite wide. Is there a reason for this? Any advice on whether I can re-run the forecasts in a way that the beginning of the fan is narrow and it expands as the horizon gets longer (similarly to the image I've attached)?

Comment: The fan width reflects the uncertainty in the forecasts. It is not subject to user choice.